# Want link to open in new window

Tags: html, target

Why is this not opening in a new window?

```
<a href="http://www.authorsden.com/visit/viewwork.asp?id=49784&AuthorID=157940">
  <img src="authors_den.jpg" target="blank" alt="Authors Den Link"
       width="175px" border="0"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target is called `_blank` not `blank`. Plus you should use it on the anchor tag `a`.

```
<a target="_blank" alt="Authors Den Link" href="http://www.authorsden.com/visit/viewwork.asp?id=49784&AuthorID=157940">
    <img src="authors_den.jpg" width="175px" border="0"/>
</a>
```

Comment: `blank` and `_blank` are technically both valid, where `blank` is a name of a window/frame. Different behavior, and probably `_blank` is what OP wanted, but I just felt the need to nitpick.

Comment: @Madmartigan Okay, this _might_ be true. When I learned HTML I guess it was not valid. -- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Comment: Although [w3schools is not an authority](http://w3fools.com/), the page you link to correctly mentions *`"framename"`* as a valid value, so it would be legit if your "framename" is `blank`.

Comment: Do you need to dig up an RFC before you are satisfied? It doesn't really matter which source you are refering to. Of course this is not an official definition! `blank` can be a framename okay, but this is not what the OP wanted, right? Nitpicking is okay, but doesn't really help here. -- Problem solved. EOM.

Comment: It helps if you want to actually understand the `target` attribute rather than misunderstand it.

Answer (score 4):

You probably meant "_blank" instead of "blank" but the bigger issue is:

The `target="_blank"` part should be on the `<a>` tag, not the `<img>` tag.

```
<a target="blank" href="http://www.authorsden.com/visit/viewwork.asp?id=49784&AuthorID=157940">
    <img src="authors_den.jpg" alt="Authors Den Link" width="175px" border="0"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the attribute

```
target="_blank"
```

to your anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote    $(function () {
>           $("a").attr("target","_blank");
>       });